# What is the most accurate way to recreate an arbitrary sound using a list of fixed sounds?

Tags: algorithm, audio

I want to create an algorithm which can most accurately replicate a given input audio source (music) by playing from a predetermined list of sounds. [This](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-6e2c0v4sBM) is an example of what I want to do, but this uses all 88 keys of the piano in various volumes, while I only have a predetermined list of audio files.

Assuming the sounds overlap (multiple instances of the sounds can be played at once) then what's the best algorithm (or existing software, if any) which can do this?

Comment: Reads like a go at [dictionary compression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dictionary_coder).

Comment: @greybeard the sound isn't composed of the original sounds, I want to add together the sounds to create an arbitrary waveform

Comment: For stationary signals, there's [Fourier synthesis](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fourier_synthesis) - ?

Comment: @greybeard Fourier synthesis would work if the sounds could be played an arbitrary number of times, including fractions and negatives.  But not for a fixed number of audio files that play at a set volume.

Answer (score 1):

This is a very hard problem, and I don't believe that there is a good algorithm.

First, let's describe the problem to be sure it is right.  You have a collection `X` of audio samples. You can play any combination of them starting at any time `t`.  So the number of waveforms you have to insert is the number in the collection times the number of times they can start.

You want a list of which ones to play, and when to play them (possibly multiple at the same time), to approximate a given wave form.  In other words you want to find a subset of the options that adds to the approximation.

If we just wanted to sum or approximate at one point, you'd get the standard [Subset Sum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subset_sum_problem) problem.  Which can be solved by dynamic programming.  BUT dynamic programming requires a state which is the number of things in your set times the number of possible values you could sum to. This state is huge.  You can make it smaller by grouping values into a smaller number of buckets.  (This is fine for approximating.)

But we want to approximate not at one point, but at many.  And even a small number of buckets at 20 points makes a combinatorial explosion with too much state to handle.

Therefore I wouldn't hope to find a perfect algorithm.  Instead I would recommend looking up things like simulated annealing and genetic algorithms to randomly explore and find a reasonable solution in a reasonable time.

Good luck! (Literally, given the randomness I'm recommending.)

---

A note on what kind of combination I'm thinking of.

Imagine having a pool of 10,000 candidates.  Each turn you randomly do one of these things to create a new candidate.  Take one and remove a sample.  Take one and move the timing of a sample.  Take one and add a random sample.  Take 2 and a cutover time, and do the samples from the first before then the samples from the other after.

You then compare your new candidate with a random other candidate, using the simulated annealing temperature to randomly decide which to keep (but over time give a growing preference to the better one).

It will take a lot of calculation, but I believe you'll wind up with some good candidates.